# kaa sandbox is not accessible on 9080 on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, kaa

I have followed all steps mentioned [here](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Launching+the+Kaa+Sandbox+AMI).

The admin is working on port 8080, when trying to access 
http://amazonn-instance:9080/sandbox

am getting the error

```
This site can’t be reached 
refused to connect.
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Sandbox installation/AWS EC2](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Getting-started/#sandbox-installation) documentation page. As mentioned there, if your Kaa Sandbox interface does not start due to an error, you can see the error details in the Sandbox log records.

Answer (score 0):

in Amazon AWS dashboard change security group and assign correct security group

Please see screenshots

[image]